# Visual Studio-Code is not finding Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am setting up a simple console project to connect to a database using a connection string.  My problem is the project is NOT finding one of the required libraries at runtime.

[image]

When I run the console app the application fails.
[image]

I go look at the csproj file to ensure I have added the library. I run the command 'dotnet restore -force'. and it finds the library and reports no errors.

The same code works on other developer machines (Windows laptops)  but it does not work on my MAC. I am using NuGet Package Manager and NuGet Gallery to ensure I have installed them correctly.  I have uninstalled the libraries and re-installed them.  It still does not work.

[image]

Have I done something wrong? Any suggestions or recommendations would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found a work around.

I change the usage from System.Extensions to MicroSoft.Extensions.Configuration.  I followed the instructions form this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56256722/how-to-add-an-app-config-in-visual-studio-code) on how to get the connection string.